How to get rid of white space at top when using NavigationStack in SwiftUI?
Here i have a small prototype in which i'm using TabView with NavigationStack but somehow it left white space at top.
Here is the POC
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            NavigationStack {
                TabView {
                    Color.red
                        .tag(0)
                    Color.blue
                        .tag(1)
                    Color.green
                        .tag(2)
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}

This is the out put


Note, TabView should not be inside a NavigationStack, it should be the top most container.

I found out by my self. Just set .background(.white) to TabView and bingo. Now all views show in full screen.
